# Strong gas odor 1997 VW Eurovan

Tags: vw, gasoline, smell, euro-van

Not strictly the gas cap...mechanic cannot diagnose the problem.  I am the original owner, vehicle has 100 K in excellent condition except for this and the air conditioning also just went out (mechanic doesn't want to fix this either)..Denver area.  Help

Comment: Take it to a new mechanic? If you are taking it to a VW service shop (dealership), I will tell you they are really lousy to deal with. I'm sure someone will take your money in exchange for fixing the issue. The gas odor could be a charcoal canister issue or a purge line gone bad. The A/C I'm sure you can find a tech who will fix it without issue.